# File.GetFiles or File.EnumerateFiles locks the files?

Tags: c#, file

This code works:

```
File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file), true);
```

This does not work:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder))
{
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file), true);
}
```

It gives an exepction in the first file:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Palomas\IMG_20130215_134854.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Why?
Looks like Directory.GetFiles or Directory.EnumerateFiles locks the file

Comment: Sounds like it's locked in the destination folder to me. `GetFiles()` and `EnumerateFiles()` definitely don't lock files.

Comment: The destionation folder is empty, and in the execption it shows the path of the source file

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder)` returns full path, don't you want to get filename and combine with destination folder? i.e. `File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destinationFolder, Path.GetFileName(file));`

Comment: Note that the `Directory.GetFiles()` returns a `string[]` so by that point it isn't actually touching the files you just have an array of strings.

Comment: It has to be locked somewhere else; there's no other explanation.

Comment: Ohhh I think I am trying to copy and paste in the same place... an error in the foreach because in each interation file is the whole path, not the filename :)

Comment: the question is still open and valid, does GetFiles lock files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple error in the foreach.

I was trying to copy and paste in the same place.

Fixed this way:

```
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder))
    {
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destinationFolder, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - was doing Directory.GetFiles on a folder and then passing each file path/name into a call to SQL Server to bulk load the file, and was getting the file locked by another process error. It looks like Directory.GetFiles momentarily locks the files - how fast the locks are released depends on how fast the operating system is on the machine where the folder is at. I think releasing the locks may just lag behind a bit. In my application I put a 30 second pause {Thread.Sleep(30000)} after the Directory.GetFiles statement and before anything else - that solved my problem.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm having this same problem.  I have lists of files, and sometimes a given list will be a `*` or `*.*` or `*.xyz`, and I have a separate method call that expands those to the actual files and subdirectories and such.  Later on (usually 10-20 seconds), when another method reads those file paths out of a `List<>`, they are locked.  They are not OS locked (they're on a shared UNC path), and I can copy them manually through Windows...  but the same files always come back as locked when the utility is executing.